# How to get the text of a td without the div within the td

Tags: jquery, html-table

The html looks like this:

```
<td class="desc-col">
    Good Stuff
    <div class="options">
        <ul>            
            <li>
                <em>Price</em>
                    $800.00
            </li>                                                                   
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="desc-col">
    Awesome Stuff
    <div class="options">
        <ul>            
            <li>
                <em>Price</em>
                    $200.00
            </li>                                                               
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

and I want to get the text within the td but do not want anything else. I have tried this but it does not get only the td:

```
Array = [];
$("td.desc-col").each(function() {
  Array.push( $(this).text());});
```

How would I simply get this:

```
["Good Stuff","Awesome Stuff"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get all child elements (including raw DOM text nodes), then pick the first one:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3s6n4d5y/5/

```
var Array = [];
$("td.desc-col").each(function () {
    Array.push($(this).contents().first().text());
});
alert(Array[0]);   // "Good stuff"
alert(Array[1]);   // "Awesome Stuff"
```

If you need to trim the text, use `jQuery.trim()` or `$.trim()` as `"string".trim` is not supported on all browsers.

You can simplify this, as `A. Wolff` suggests, with `map()` and `get()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/3s6n4d5y/6/

```
var Array = $("td.desc-col").map(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).contents().first().text());
}).get();
console.log(Array);
```

**Update:** If the content may not be the first element, you can `filter()` by node type:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3s6n4d5y/8/

```
var Array = $("td.desc-col").map(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;     // Node.TEXT_NODE
      }).first().text());
}).get();
console.log(Array);
```

Comment: You could use `map()` & `get()` ;)

Comment: @A. Wolff: True, feel free to add you own answer.

Comment: That's ok, i just updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3s6n4d5y/6/  The important part is already in your answer, using `contents()`

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
Array = [];
$("td.desc-col").each(function () {
    Array.push($(this).contents()[0].nodeValue.trim());
});
console.log(Array)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/523fytmy/1/)**

This iterates through the cells, gets the content of each cell, takes the first node (trims the content) and appends it to your array.

Comment: Why would you ever iterate with `each` to get only the *first element* of a collection???

Comment: nice answer +1. But what if `Good Stuff` is in the middle of tags such as `<td class="desc-col"><span>blah</span>...<span>blah</span>Good Stuff<span>blah</span></td>` how to detect this

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak - Well then you'd need a different method of selection, either based on the text itself, or its position.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Because I hadn't had my coffee yet! ;)

Comment: @j08691 I think it should look like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27426471/492258)

Answer (score 0):

Or try this...

```
var text = $('.desc-col').clone().find('.options').remove().end().text();
```

Hope that helps :)

OOPS, missed the array part. Here's it as an array:

```
var textArray = $('.desc-col').clone().append('**').find('.options').remove().end().text().trim().split('**');
```

-Ted

Comment: Reasonable alternative, but `.options` is very specific. The question suggests "do not want anything else". Use a wider match.

Comment: yeah, I like your answer better now that I'm looking at this

Answer (score 0):

Here is piece of code that detects any text in `<td>` where ever it is positioned

```js
$("td.desc-col").contents().each(function(index, elem) {
  if ($.trim(elem.nodeValue) != '' && elem.nodeType == 3)
    alert($.trim(elem.nodeValue))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="desc-col">
      <span>some text</span>
      Good Stuff
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <em>Price</em>
            $800.00
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
some other good stuff
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```